# How to access Spring 3 MVC validator results in JSP without using form taglib

Tags: java, jsp, data-binding, spring-mvc

I have a simple Spring 3 MVC form using jsp taglibs.  I need to add a class based on whether a field within the form has any errors associated with it or not.  Here is a snipet of my HTML:

```
<div class="control-group error"> <!-- HERE: binding.hasErrors() ? "error" : "" -->
    <form:label path="username" cssClass="control-label">User Name</form:label>
    <div class="controls">
        <form:input path="username" cssClass="span3"/>
        <form:errors path="username" cssClass="help-inline" />
    </div>
</div>
```

So on the first line the class attribute has two classes "control-group" and "error".  I need to add error class only if that field has an error associated with it.  I know the WebDataBinder is included in the page somehow, but I don't know how to access it.  Essentially I just want to execute some good old fashion <%= binding.hasError() ? "error" : "" %>, but how do I get access to the binder in the page?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While this is a little more obscure I think it's simpler because it's a single line which is what it would be if I were just using scriplets like any sane Java dev should.  Taglibs need to die die die die, then die some more.  They are horrible and I can't believe Java devs still think they actually help and not waste our utter time.  PHP developers laugh at us when we use those things.

```
<div class="control-group ${requestScope['org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.user'].hasFieldErrors('firstName') ? 'error' : ''}">
```

Comment: So it's "obscure way" I added with small font ;)

Comment: This works. Note that `user` here is the name of you data model class.

Answer (score 15):

Did you try [`<spring:hasBindErrors>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#spring.tld.hasBindErrors) tag (I don't understand what you mean writing "without using form taglib")?

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<spring:hasBindErrors name="yourCommandName">
  <c:if test="${errors.hasFieldErrors('username')}">
    <c:set var="errorClass" value="error" />
  </c:if>
</spring:hasBindErrors>

<div class="control-group <c:out value='${errorClass}' />">
```

*Edit after comments:*

Inside `<spring:hasBindErrors>` tag there is `errors` variable (see [`Errors` interface](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html)) bound to actual binding errors. You can check if field has errors via `errors.hasFieldErrors(fieldName)`.

---

<sub>And really obscure way to get field errors without any tag is `requestScope['org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.yourCommandName'].hasFieldErrors('username')`...</sub>

Comment: That just looks at errors in total.  I need to know if there was an error for a field on that object.  I hate taglibs.  JSP was simpler without them.

Comment: What I mean is can I directly access the BindingResults from within JSP without using spring: or form:.  Spring has put the BindingResults in the page using a hard coded property that all the  tags know about.  So what is that secret name request.getRequestParmeter("??????")?

Comment: You can use `errors.hasFieldErrors(fieldName)` inside this tag (still, I recommend usings tags), see my edit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work with 3.0 because errors isn't defined.  I found a solution that didn't require taglibs because they are horrible, and I can't believe Java devs still think they aren't wasting their time with them.  I found a simpler approach.

Answer (score 4):

There is a better way to get the error message

```
<spring:hasBindErrors name="yourCommandName">
    ${errors.hasFieldErrors('userId') ? errors.getFieldError('userId').defaultMessage : ''}
</spring:hasBindErrors>
```

And one liner

```
 ${requestScope['org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.user'].hasFieldErrors('emailId') ? requestScope['org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.user'].getFieldError('emailId').defaultMessage : ''}
```