# Need to Combine Spring Binding Errors and Custom Exceptions into Same DIV

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I need to display SpringMVC's Form errors, as well as any custom "Exception" messages that I store in the request, in the **same** DIV on my page.

Right now they're in separate DIV's:

```
<!-- Validation Errors -->
<spring:hasBindErrors htmlEscape="true" name="model">                
    <c:if test="${errors.errorCount gt 0}">                 
        <div class="errors_div clsErrorTblBorder">
            <c:forEach items="${errors.allErrors}" var="error">
                <div class="errors clsWhiteBack blue">                      
                    <myForm:message messageLinkClass="errorLink"
                                error="${error}" />
                </div>
            </c:forEach>                
        </div>
    </c:if>   
</spring:hasBindErrors>

<!-- Exceptions -->
<c:if test="${fn:length(requestScope.exceptions) > 0}">
    <div class="errors_div clsMsgTblBorder">
        <c:forEach items="${requestScope.exceptions}" var="exception">
            <div class="messages clsWhiteBack">
                ${exception}
            </div>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
</c:if>
```

The **shared** condition for an Error DIV should be,

```
${fn:length(requestScope.exceptions) || errors.errorCount gt 0}
```

But it's impossible to test this condition, because:

- You don't get the `errors` var. until you do `<spring:hasBindErrors>`
- Anything inside `<spring:hasBindErrors>` only applies if you have
  binding errors. If you don't (e.g. if you only have a custom
  Exception message) its logic won't execute, so you can't move the
  custom "exceptions" check inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some clues from this thread: [How to access Spring 3 MVC validator results in JSP without using form taglib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204649/how-to-access-spring-3-mvc-validator-results-in-jsp-without-using-form-taglib) , and here's the working result:

```
    <c:if test="${fn:length(requestScope.exceptions) > 0 || 
requestScope['org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.model'].hasFieldErrors()}">
```

The 2nd part of this condition checks for Binding Errors even prior to the tag Spring:hasBindErrors.